# How to delete table row in Python

Tags: python

Hey guys so basically I don't know how to make a code on how to delete table rows selected by the user in python gui since I only have few experience in python gui. We are not allowed to use sql that's what makes it harder for me, hopefully I could get a feedback about this, thank you!

```
global Indexes
global trueIndex

emailCheck = False
at = False
dotcom = False
emailinfo = False
minorCheck = False

list= [['ID', 'Name', 'Email', 'Birthday']]
recentIndex = []
Indexes = [1]
trueIndex = [1]
deleteIndexes = []
ID = 1

def callback(event):
    print(event.widget._values)

    custid.config(state = NORMAL)
    custid.delete('1.0', END)
    custid.insert(1.0, list[event.widget._values][0])
    custid.config(state=DISABLED)

    custname.set(list[event.widget._values] [1])
    custemail.set(list[event.widget._values] [2])
    custbday.set(list[event.widget._values] [3])
    indexLocation = event.widget._values
    recentIndex.append(indexLocation)
    print(recentIndex)

def createtable():

  for i in range(len(list)):
   for j in range(len(list[0])):
        mgrid = Entry(window, width = 10, bg='yellow')
        mgrid.insert(END,list[i][j])
        mgrid._values =i
        mgrid.grid(row = i + 5, column = j + 5)
        mgrid.bind("<Button-1>", callback)


#this is where im having problems at
def delete():
     list.pop(0)


#Saves the input of the user
def save():
    # Birthday
    global ID


    # FinalCheck

    if emailinfo == True and nameInfo == True and minorCheck == True:
        custid.config(state=NORMAL)
        for x in range(len(Indexes)):
            if trueIndex[x] in Indexes:
                print("Continue")
            elif trueIndex[x] not in Indexes:
                print("Lapse Found")
                Indexes[-1] = trueIndex[x]
                break
        print(str(Indexes) + "Indexes")
        print(str(trueIndex) + "true Indexes")


        custid.delete(1.0, END)
        list.append([Indexes[-1], custname.get(), custemail.get(), custbday.get()])
        createtable()
        ID = ID + 1
        Indexes.append(ID)
        trueIndex.append(ID)
        custid.insert('1.0', Indexes[-1])
        custid.config(state=DISABLED)
        print(trueIndex[x])

        print(list)
        msgbox("Saved", "Recorded")


    else:

        msgbox("Error", "Recorded")
```

I just need to figure out if how do I delete the clicked table row by the user, thank you!

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I am using pycharm